# Prince of Yerushalaim named Merishadek?

Tags: malchut-royalty, navi-prophets, yerushalayim-jerusalem

My auto mechanic is an Eastern European Jew whose father was a Charedi student in Romania (the man himself is not a very observant Jew at all, judging by appearance and mannerism), and frequently lectures me on the prophets and their writings. He often speaks of a Prince of Yerushalaim named Merishadek (that is what I decipher through his accent), but upon a quick flip through some books on scripture and a few Google searches, I cannot find any man by this name. Who is he?

Comment: What does your mechanic say about this Merishadek?

Comment: Something about hating Muslims. I usually tune him out because he is so vehemently anti Islam

Comment: @ElyBeauEastman, kol hakavod on ignoring his vehemence, however what does Malchitzedek have to do with Islamophobia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be Malchitzedek, traditionally identified as Shem, son of Noah. He was a priest and the ruler of Yerushalayim* in the time of Avraham Avinu, although it was then known as Shalem (see Parshat Lech-Lecha and commentary ad loc.).